# Preserve creation time stamp after modification

Tags: buffers, save

I want to modify files with `vim` without changing the creation time stamps.

The docs doesn't seem to mention anything about such possibility.

I'd like to achieve this without turning off the swap/recover feature.

One alternative would be to store the time somewhere and then overwrite it when exiting, I guess.

Comment: What OS are you on? Some OS' don't store creation times, so it could make a difference.

Comment: I'm on OS X 10.8.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sato's answer would be correct on a standard Unix-derivative, where `ctime` is often mistaken for creation time but is actually inode change time, and "preserving" it doesn't really make sense. However, I asked what OS the poster is using because Mac OS X maintains a separate create time that is an actual creation date and time, and isn't updated by modifying the file in place or changing the file's mode or anything like that, all of which do update `ctime`.

You can see the creation time by doing a Get Info on a file in the Finder or `GetFileInfo <file>` from a command line (`GetFileInfo` requires the developer tools to be installed). The time can be modified using `SetFile -d <datetime> <file>` (also requiring developer tools).

So it seems reasonable (to me, don't know about Bram :-) ) to ask for vim to maintain the create time on Mac OS X, by copying the create time from the original file to the new file, but it clearly doesn't, and glancing through the vim sources, I don't see anywhere where it does so. So, unfortunately, it appears the answer to the poster's question is "It's not currently possible." Because Mac OS X (with developer tools) does allow getting and setting the create time from the command line, it may be possible to put together a vim script that does that, although that's (currently) beyond my vim scripting abilities.

**Edit**

I decided to play around with scripting something and actually got it to work!

Add the following to your .vimrc:

```
autocmd BufReadPre * call SaveFileCreateTime()
autocmd BufWritePost * call RestoreFileCreateTime()

function! SaveFileCreateTime()
    let l:path = expand('%:p')

    if l:path != ''
        let b:created = system("GetFileInfo -d " . shellescape(bufname("%")))
    endif
endfunction

function! RestoreFileCreateTime()
    if exists('b:created')
        execute system(
          \ 'SetFile -d ' .
          \ shellescape(b:created) .
          \ ' ' .
          \ shellescape(bufname("%")))
    endif
endfunction
```

That sets auto commands to run before a file is read (for editing in a buffer, not for things like `:read`) and after it's written. The first calls `SaveFileCreateTime` which uses `GetFileInfo -d` to get the file's create time and store it in the buffer local variable `b:created`. After a file is written, `RestoreFileCreateTime` is called. If `b:created` exists, it's used in a `system` command to use `SetFile -d` to set the time.

Here's an example:

```
$ echo hello >file.txt
$ stat -c%z file.txt;GetFileInfo -d file.txt
2015-11-07 11:44:04.000000000 -0800
11/07/2015 11:44:04
$ vim file.txt
a earth<esc>:wq
$ cat file.txt
hello earth
$ stat -c%z file.txt;GetFileInfo -d file.txt
2015-11-07 11:44:24.000000000 -0800
11/07/2015 11:44:04
```

You can see the inode change time (as displayed by `stat`) has changed, but the file create time (as displayed by `GetFileInfo`) hasn't. Success!

As noted above, this requires the developer tools to be installed to get GetFileInfo and SetFile. Also, this is my first real script, so feel free to point out all the hideous errors I've made!

Comment: Would a vim script be a wrapper or alter `vim`'s runtime using those tools, which I do have installed btw, to preserve the creation date?

Comment: It would be some functions you put in your .vimrc. I decided to play around with it and actually got something that works! I'll edit my answer to include that.

Comment: @1.61803 Ok, edited my answer to include the vimscript to save and restore the time. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: I tested it while `vimdiff`ing files owned by root and user. So far so good. You should post this in the [Vim Tips wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Vim_Tips_Wiki). That was a great answer, thanks.

Comment: Btw, your `stat` command is for Linux, I guess. In OS X 10.8.5 you'd use `stat -f %Sc`.

Comment: I noticed that `atime` is not reported in Finder. Could you add it to your script? I don't want to butcher it :)

Comment: @1.61803 I use OS X but I have a bunch of gnu stuff installed. I didn't realize `stat` was one of them but evidently it is. Modifying the script to preserve `atime` would probably just require using an appropriate `stat` command and then a `touch`, although should `atime` be preserved? vim is accessing the file, so I'd expect `atime` to be updated. I'll add it to the Vim Tips wiki, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: `atime` should be reported in Get Info pane's Last Opened, don't you think?

Comment: @1.61803 One would think, but a little experimenting shows that's not the case, at least on Snow Leopard and Yosemite. If you open a file from the Finder, Last Opened is updated, but if you just do something like `cat` it, `stat` reports the access time is updated (as expected), but a Get Info doesn't show an updated Last Opened. I don't know where the Last Opened time is stored nor any way to get it except in Get Info.

Comment: `mdls --name kMDItemLastUsedDate foobar` gets it, but I still haven't found a way to set Last Opened, maybe there's some other OS X specific command to achieve that.

Comment: As **@anothernode** noticed in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34123076/osx-how-to-get-the-creation-modification-time-of-a-file-from-the-command-lin):

Apparently `GetFileInfo` and `SetFile` are deprecated since Xcode 6.
At least, `man GetFileInfo` says so and also [the Xcode release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html#:~:text=GetFileInfo)
(search for 'GetFileInfo' on the page).

Comment: @duthen Yes, they've both been deprecated for a while, but are still included in Command Line Tools for Xcode 14.2, posted December 13, 2022.

Answer (score 5):

Add `set backupcopy=yes` to your vimrc file to preserve file creation time on macOS.

For more info, see `:help 'backupcopy'`.

Source: [How can I get VIM to maintain the creation date for a file? (OS X)](https://superuser.com/a/811805/59284)

Comment: It works, thanks!

Comment: @1.61803 Sure! :-)

Answer (score 1):

What you want is not possible to implement in UNIX using standard userspace functions.  The `ctime` of a file is updated automatically by the kernel [when the file's `inode` changes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31255/on-what-occasion-will-inode-change/31261).  Unlike `atime` and `mtime`, there is no user-accessible function to set `ctime` to an arbitrary value.

Comment: Could `vim`, instead of swapping files, just `cp test.swp test.txt`?

Comment: @1.61803, `less test.swp` should answer your question.